# Can an abstract superclass check the instance of itself (to determine the subclass) at runtime?

Tags: java, inheritance

Let's say I have this piece of code:

```java
public abstract class InferenceRule {

    protected abstract void provability(Line line) throws InferenceException;

    public void checkProvability(Line line) throws InferenceException {
        // ??
    }

}
```

There are unique subclasses for different types of `InferenceRule`. They would implement the abstract method `#provability(Line)`. Each line object contains an InferenceRule.

```java
public class Line {

    private InferenceRule inferenceRule;

    public InferenceRule getInferenceRule() {
        return inferenceRule;
    }

}
```

I want to code it so that for the method `InferenceRule#checkProvability(Line)` could check the line's inference rule and see if that rule is the same instance (or the subclass) of this inference rule. I.e.

`line.getInferenceRule() instanceof this`

But this will always return true because `InferenceRule#checkProvability(Line)` is in the abstract superclass and all subclasses of InferenceRule is, by necessity, instances of the superclass InferenceRule. So, is there a way for the superclass to determine what subclass it itself is an instance of (at runtime)? that way, I could check if the subclass of this object is the same instance of the inference rule contained by a Line.

Here are a few exmaples of implementations of the InferenceRule class:
1. Final, non-abstract subclass class

```java
public final class AssumptionIR extends InferenceRule {

    @Override
    protected void provability(Line line) throws InferenceException {
        // implementation
    }

    // other methods unique to this class
}
```

2. Abstract subclass

```java
public abstract class DischargeIR extends InferenceRule {
    // other methods unique to this class
}
```

3. Anonymous class which can extend DischargeIR or InferenceRule itself.

```java
public static final InferenceRule IR_MODUS_POLLENS = new InferenceRule() {
        @Override
        protected void provability(Line line) throws InferenceException {
            // implementation
        }
    };

public static final DischargeIR IR_IF_INTRO = new DischargeIR() {
        @Override
        protected void provability(Line line) throws InferenceException {
            // implementation
        }
    };
```

Each anonymous class should only be the same instance as itself (in this case, `IR_IF_INTRO` should be the same instance as `DischargeIR`, whereas `IR_IF_INTRO` should not be the same instance as `IR_MODUS_POLLENS`), and not its abstract superclass.
Each non-abstract sub-class (AssumpIR) should not be the same instance of its superclass.

Comment: Yes, you can do it the way you want, but this isn't a very OOP-friendly solution. I suggest you learn more about polymorphism and how you can leverage it to do what you want. For example, you can call `provability()` in the super class and it will call the correct version in the subclass depending on the current object's type. Or you can override `checkProvability()` in each subclass.

Comment: "There are unique subclasses for different types of InferenceRule. They would implement the abstract method #provability(Line)." Please show an example subclass like you describe here in words. That will help us be able to provide more specific suggestions. See [mcve] for tips on how to create a good code example.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've updated the question. So I have an abstract superclass `InferenceRule`, which 3 classes extend: `PremiseIR`, `AssumpIR`, and `DischargeIR`. Both 3 objects have methods or fields unique to them. `PremiseIR` and `AssumpIR` are final non-abstract classes, whereas `DischargeIR` is abstract. 
The user is meant to extend (or create anonymous classes) either `DischargeIR` or `InferenceRule` itself, depending on what inference rule it is. The user is also meant to create instances of `PremiseIR` and `AssumpIR` without touching its code.

Comment: A reason why the user is allowed to implement `InferenceRule` directly is that objects that are not `PremiseIR`, `AssumpIR`, or `DischargeIR` will not have any unique methods that is not already in `InferenceRule`. If i were to create another class so that the user would be implementing it at the same level as `DischargeIR`, the class would be empty.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that using [`Class#isAssignableFrom()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)):

```
public void checkProvability(Line line) throws InferenceException {
    if(getClass().isAssignableFrom(line.getInferenceRule().getClass())) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: oh! i thought `getClass()` returns the superclass. thanks!

Comment: OK,try to print `getClass().getName()` and `line.getInferenceRule().getClass().getName()` to debug the issue.